# How i can specific encoding for javasphinx output?

Tags: java, python, utf-8, python-sphinx

I have a java project, where my java files use the "UTF-8" encoding, 'cause the comments on some classes are writted on spanish using accents.

When i run the command.

`javasphinx-apidoc -o docs/java ~/Development/Projects/code/java -f -v`

always return the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/user/Development/Projects/Docs/sphinx/myenv/bin/javasphinx-apidoc", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
    File "/Users/user/Development/Projects/Docs/sphinx/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/javasphinx/apidoc.py", line 317, in main
write_documents(documents, sources, opts)
    File "/Users/user/Development/Projects/Docs/sphinx/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/javasphinx/apidoc.py", line 112, in write_documents
f.write(document)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1464: ordinal not in range(128)``
```

I wanto to specific the encoding of the files for the apidoc can write this files using utf-8.

is this possible?

Thanks for your help.